# Dependancies for RE2 on Centos7

Tags: linux, centos, dependencies, centos7, re2

I am trying to install re2 on a centos7 vm, and I am having some trouble solving these dependencies:

```
[root@roller re2]# make testinstall
cp testinstall.cc obj
(cd obj && g++ -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib testinstall.cc -lre2 -pthread -static -o testinstall)
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [testinstall] Error 1
```

Any help would be great! :)

thanks!

Comment: I also tested with gmake, same issue

Comment: You are missing development packages, `yum install glibc-devel libstdc++-devel`

Comment: Packages already present :(

[root@roller .ssh]# yum install -y glibc-devel libstdc++-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.vorboss.net
 * extras: mirror.cov.ukservers.com
 * updates: mirror.cov.ukservers.com
Package glibc-devel-2.17-106.el7_2.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libstdc++-devel-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@roller .ssh]#

Comment: I did not notice `-static` flag, `yum install glibc-static libstdc++-static` may help.

Comment: That seemed to help:

[root@roller re2]# make testinstall
cp testinstall.cc obj
(cd obj && g++ -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib testinstall.cc -lre2 -pthread -static -o testinstall)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libpthread.a(libpthread.o): In function sem_open': (.text+0x682b): warning: the use ofmktemp' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
obj/testinstall
PASS
(cd obj && g++ -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib testinstall.cc -lre2 -pthread -o testinstall)
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib obj/testinstall
    PASS